# Troubles reading large json file (python 3.5)

Tags: python, json

I have been struggling for hours with a large json file (1.4gb).

My code is as follows.

```
import json
json_data = open('data.json')
d = json.load(json_data)
```

I keep getting the error. Am I missing somwthing too obvious here?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-20-68c726931a15>", line 1, in <module>
    d=json.load(json_data)

  File "C:\Users\dvargas\Anaconda3\lib\json\__init__.py", line 265, in load
    return loads(fp.read(),

  File "C:\Users\dvargas\Anaconda3\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]

UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8d in position 58902: character maps to <undefined>
```

Comment: You need to encode in `utf-8`. Use `json_data = open('data.json', encoding="utf8")`

Comment: I did try the encoding and it shows a different error.

Comment: Share the error with us.

Comment: `
JSONDecodeError: Expecting ',' delimiter`

Comment: It is weird, I was able to load the json without the encoding, but in py27, in another machine.

Comment: And if I use `json.loads` I get: TypeError: the JSON object must be str, not 'TextIOWrapper'

Comment: `json.loads`'s parameter must be str, bytes or bytearray. You can use `d = json.loads(json_data.read())` to give a string parameter. If you use `json.load`, it calls `read()` function inside.

Comment: Invalid jsons cause `JSONDecodeError: Expecting ',' delimiter`